# I cant get item id, value or text in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, repeater, itemtemplate

I can't get item id or value or text. How can I get the item? I'm new on asp.net and can't find clearly support on this. The codes returns null. Here my codes:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="çidden mal O_O"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
      <div class="col-md-12">
    <asp:Button ID="ekle" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" Text="Gönder" OnClick="ekle_Click" />   
                                        </div>
protected void ekle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
            Label strNewsID = (Label)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("lblID");
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + strNewsID.ToString() + "')", true);

        }
    }
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void ekle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {                                                                                                
        Label strNewsID = (Label)item.FindControl("lblID");

        if(strNewsID!=null)
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('" + strNewsID.Text +"')",true);
        }
    }
}
```